# Start/stop a service using jenkins/hudson, without sudo

Tags: services, sudo, hudson

Quick question - did some searching but couldn't seem to find anything.

I'd like to be able to stop/start a service on a Jenkins node. Is it possible to give the jenkins user permission for this WITHOUT using sudo? Or is it going to be less secure than just using sudo with the lines:

```
Defaults:jenkins !requiretty,!lecture
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/servicename
```

Thanks.

(edited to add 'hudson' to the title)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ssh plugin. You can specify a different user and execute your command without having to sudo into that user.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin

Comment: Enh.  We don't like link-only answers here.  Especially link-only answers to a product.  A little spammy.  Maybe improve this with some details about this pllugin, or how to do it with this pulgin, or like that there.